# Passing multidimensional POST data in Java

Tags: java, php

In HTML, it's possible to pass multidimensional keys, e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="user_profile[name]" />
<input type="type" name="user_profile[id]" />
```

And in my PHP script I can just access them by `$_POST['user_profile']`

Can one pass these multidimensional key-value pairs with Java?

Comment: How do you get the name and id out of `$_POST['user_profile']`?

Comment: $userProfile = $_POST['user_profile'];
$name = $userProfile['name'];

Comment: @tieTYT: In php you jsut use array access notation so `$name = $_POST['user_profile']['name'];`

Comment: You can do things like this in Stripes (a java web framework), but I'm not sure if plain old JSPs and Servlets support this.  Here's how you can do it in stripes: http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Indexed+Properties

Comment: In java, just access it as `request.getParameter("user_profile[name]");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use string manipulation technique.

**From:** `<input type="text" name="user_profile[name]">`

**To:** `<input type="text" name="user_profile_name">`

Then in JS/jQuery do:

```
$('user_profile_name')...
```

or:

If "id" element doesn't mean that much to your then do this:

```
<input type="text" name="user_profile[name]" id="user_profile_name">
```

Comment: You need to indent code by 4 spaces or surround it with backticks.